# Ruby passing attribute that may be nil

Tags: ruby

```
stanza_class.new(node.attributes if node.attributes)
```

I am passing an variables that may be nil in a method.
Is there a beautiful way of doing this in ruby?

Comment: `node.attributes if node.attributes` makes no sense. Is `node` what may be nil? then `node.attributes if node`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby on Rails, you can use the try method:

Eg.

```
node.try(:attributes)
```

This means that if `node` is `nil`, it returns `nil` instead of missing method on NilClass.

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

If you are NOT using rails, you can monkey patch the Object class yourself. The source code for the monkey patching Rails does (found at reference URL) is:

```
class Object
  def try(*a, &b)
    if a.empty? && block_given?
      yield self
    else
      __send__(*a, &b)
    end
  end
end
```

If you mean that node is never nil, but node.attributes might be nil, then you can just do:

```
stanza_class.new(node.attributes)
```

This is because

```
stanza_class.new(nil)
```

is equivalent to

```
stanza_class.new()
```

That is, arguments not passed are set to nil by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume it's `node` which may be `nil`. That's perfectly idiomatic:

```
stanza_class.new(node.attributes if node)
```

Although programmers used to [Ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/)'s would probably write:

```
stanza_class.new(node.maybe.attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stanza_class.new(*node.attributes)
```